# 32 bit JVM commits >3G virtual memory

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, jvm, 32bit-64bit

we have a 32 bit JVM running under 64 bit RHEL5 on a box which has plenty of memory (32G). For different reasons, this process requires a pretty large managed heap and permgen space -- currently, it runs with the following VM arguments:

-Xmx2200M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

I have started seeing JVM crashes recently because it - seemingly - ran out of native memory (it could not create native threads, or failed to allocate native memory, etc.). These crashes were not (directly) related to the state of the managed heap, as when those crashes happened the managed heap was ~50-70% full.
I know that the memory reserved for the managed process is close to 2.5 G which leaves not more than 0.5G for the JVM itself, BUT
- I don't understand why 0.5 isn't enough for the JVM, even if there is constant GCing going on
- the real question is this: when I connect to the process using jconsole, then it says that  (currently)

```
Committed virtual memory: 
3,211,180 kbytes
```

Which is more than 3G. I can imagine that for some reason JVM thinks that it has 
3,211,180 kbytes (3.06G) of memory is  but when it tries to go over 3G the memory allocation fails.

Any ideas on 
a) why does this happen
b) how is it possible to avoid this

Thanks.
Mate

Comment: Under 64 bit Windows 32 bit processes have use of the full 4GB address space - the operating system no longer needs to reserve space in the 32 bit address space as it can use the 64 bit address space instead.

Comment: Ok, just noticed that this is tagged linux, still I imagine it works in a similar way

Comment: Well, if it is, then I still don't understand why does it run out of native memory. :/

Comment: If by "native memory" you mean "physical memory" then its probably not - if you have a swap partition then the OS will page physical memory onto disk as required.  Its more likely that the virtual address space is fragmented, i.e. even though there is free space in the virtual address space, the free space is split over many small chunks, the largest of which is too small for the required allocation.

Comment: Yeah, likely it's running out of address space.  And even without fragmentation, 0.5G of machine heap isn't very much when you have 3.5G JVM heap.  With lots of small objects GC alone could take that much, not to mention the non-GCed portions of threads, classes, etc.

Comment: Justin: by 'native memory' I mean 'virtual address space'. We have plenty of physical memory and the process obviously does not know anything about it. The virtual address space fragmentation was my guess as well, thanks for you both. Do you have any experience regarding how managed heap size and recommended JVM native heap size relates to each other? Please note that our managed heap size is 2.2 not 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of overhead in a typical VM that is not counted in the VM accounting because it is essentially stolen by the native elements of the process - e.g. mapping in .so files that are used for performing native level code for system libraries are not counted in the base VM accounting. your typical shared library is mapped in at the top GB of memory, so if you try to allocate memory into this region you will be denied, because it would overrun with the shared libraries' memory region - memory allocation on most OS's is performed by a simple bar that is raised when you ask for more memory. When you ask for memory and the bar conflicts with other uses, then it simply fails. Most of the details that follow are about this.

You need to avoid needing so much memory in a 32bit process. This is the fundamental challenge. It is trivial to get a 64bit VM that will allow you to make use of so much more memory than would be otherwise accessible - it is just simply usable in this situation.

If you are using a 32bit process, there is a high probability that you are encountering the effective address space limit of the 32bit process. For windows, this is a maximum of about 3GB - anything above this is reserved for I/O space and the kernel. You can move this, but it has a tendency to break applications/drivers that are designed for the 32bit OS.

For Linux, you end up with ~3GB of usable addressable RAM per process, the rest is used up by things like the kernel and mapped in shared libraries. The limit is referred to as the 'address space limit', and I presume it can be tuned.

How to avoid it? Well, for the most part, you can't, it's a physical limitation of the 32bit address space and the needs of having the kernel/IO in the same address space as the process for a 32bit OS.

With 64 bit OS's you have (most of) all of the 64 bit address space to play around with, which is extensively more than you need to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks -- I think I understand the memory limits and the implications of address space constraints. My main problem is that I don't understand why the JVM runs out of native memory -- I thought 0.5G should be enough for temporary space for GC and things like that. We can certainly move to a 64 bit JVM, but it would be nice to know what causes the JVM to use 700M extra space, but there are no good tools for debugging the JVM itself.

Comment: Start with jmap - it is the equivalent of pmap for java processes. The probability is that it doesn't run out of 'actual memory' it runs out of usable memory. You should look at the memory map as generated from /proc/&lt;pid&gt;/maps - which illustrates the memory utilization of the application. memory use is much more than just the base numbers you state, you also have JIT memory, guard pages, mapped in shared objects. If you're having a memory variation of 350MB in a process, then you're not pooling memory enough. This is a regular issue in long lived services.

Comment: Hi, thanks -- I don't generally believe in pooling managed objects as basically you put a pooling layer on the top of the GC which itself has pooling logic. Regarding jmap: I see the mapped shared objects' memory footprint but that seems to be negligible. The JVM internals seem to consume too much (?) memory for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a JVM it allocates it maximum size immediately.  How much of that memory is used doesn't really matter.  Your application can address about 3 GB of which about 2.3 GB you have allocated to heap and perm gen.  The rest is available for shared libraries (typically around 200 MB) and thread stacks.

Worrying about why you can't use the full 3 GB of address isn't very useful when the solution is relatively trivial (use a 64-bit JVM) I am assuming you don't have any shared libraries which are only available in 32-bit.  However if you do have additional shared libraries they can easily be using 100s of MB.